# How to get the polygons from a shapefile that has been imported into PostGIS by a lat/lon query

Tags: postgis, geometry, query

I have imported the "water_polygons" from https://osmdata.openstreetmap.de/data/water-polygons.html and finally mangaged to setup PostGIS in a docker container.
So the database is working:

```
select gid,x,y from water_polygons limit 4;
 gid  |  x   |  y  
------+------+-----
    1 |    1 |  41
    2 |  -11 | -72
    3 |  -11 | -72
    4 |  148 | -11
```

1. I want to throw a query like "give me the shapes within this rectangle".
2. How do I transform the resulting geometry column into seomething readable? It seems to be a binary thingy.

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works

Comment: This is what all I tried! I did not know anything about postgis till yesterday. My only goal is to get polygons from the oceans by providing lat/lon coordinates. Why? Because the natural=coastline keys in openstreetmap are a bit complicated to interpret. So, since there is no public API to query these information, I decided to install that server and put in the shapefile. And here we are :-) ! So I guess an expert could simply post a proper query and explain how to read that geometry column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [ST_MakeEnvelope](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_MakeEnvelope.html) with the [intersect operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57319206/what-is-the-meaning-of-in-postgresql) (&&) to select features in a rectangle and [ST_AsText](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_AsText.html) to make the geometries readable:

```
SELECT *, 
       st_astext(geom) 
FROM water
WHERE water.geom && ST_MakeEnvelope(13, 57, 13.3, 57.3, 4326)
```

[image]

Comment: You are the hero! That´s what I need! THANK YOU!